# How to get Simple-Peer type intellisense in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, simple-peer

I have installed packages via `npm` like

```
npm i simple-peer
npm i @types/simple-peer
```

and then referenced it in `angular.json` like

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js"
],
```

Simple-Peer is working fine 
but unable to get intellisense.

How it is possible?

Comment: Another Tip :  Never import js file into index.html file instead make a entry in angular.json file

Comment: @PardeepJain thanks for your useful tip. What about intellisense?

Comment: not sure, but may be some plugin is there for your editor

Answer (score 3):

You're quite close as you have already installed @types/simple-peer

Now try creating a declaration file named **typings.d.ts** in the src folder or whatever the root of your project is.

Then type the following in the newly created typings file:

```
declare var SimplePeer: import('simple-peer').SimplePeer;
```

In main.ts, place the following line at the top of your imports (just to keep it separate)

```
///<reference path="typings.d.ts"/>
```

In your ts component, you should be able to import (etc):

```
import { Instance, SignalData } from 'simple-peer';
```

In my case, I'm only using Instance as other usage just didn't make sense when strongly typed. So, I have peer as a type of Instance as shown:

```
peer: Instance;
```

Now you should be able to explore your options via intellisense.
Let me know if this still didn't work so I can check properly as I implemented this a while back.

Also, if you managed to improve usage, share such improvements.

Hope this helps.
Thanks

For more information on declaration files:
https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#typings

Answer (score 0):

Declare the line below at the top of your component or service.

```
declare var SimplePeer: any;
```

Now you are ready to use it anywhere like

```
let peer = new SimplePeer({ initiator: true, trickle: false })
```